# How to add extra read more button for CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, web, ckeditor

I'm using [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) to add a nice text editor using javascript in my website and it is working great, all I need is to add a read more button for it.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by javascript Where your article renders add javascript there

```
var article = "article content"
var visible_string = string.substring(0, 1000);// Visible characters 0 to 10000

function viewMore(){

//Replace the element where the content is by .innerHTML property = article

}
```

and then give them a read more